# Excel DNA XLL Config - Setting Comments, Description and Company

Tags: excel, excel-addins, excel-dna, xll

I see that in the ExcelDna.dna (config) file I can set the "Name" of an XLL, which translates to the TITLE on the Excel/Options/Addins screen.  But I was wondering if there was an easy way to set Comments (description) or Company name.   Much thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is certainly not an 'easy' way. I recall seeing some (undocumented) registry keys that a COM add-in would write, and these seemed to work for an .xll add-in too.

For example, on my machine I see the Analysis ToolPak displays a description in the add-ins dialog - "Provides data analysis tools...". Searching for this string in the registry, I find a bunch of entries here:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\Installer\Components\B65A737451FC40A46A0FA969443BD207`

but the relevant value is somewhat obscure:

`zn=BVK(8A$!!!!!MKKSkExcelAddinATPFilesIntl_1033<Analysis ToolPak\Provides data analysis tools for statistical and engineering analysis`

If you add an extra value under the same key it does get displayed in the add-ins dialog, but I couldn't get it hooked up with the actual add-in entry . . .

Comment: Thanks Govert,  that's what I was afraid of, but not the end of the world!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
In a VBA XLAM-Add-In-project this information is in the "core.xml" (tag <dc:description>) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
    xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
    <dc:title>Name of AddIns</dc:title>
    <dc:creator>Mike Miller</dc:creator>
    <cp:keywords>Core XML example</cp:keywords>
    <dc:description>Description for demonstration</dc:description>
    <cp:lastModifiedBy>Miller, Mike</cp:lastModifiedBy>
    <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2013-01-25T07:58:19Z</dcterms:created>
    <dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2020-09-29T13:06:15Z</dcterms:modified>
</cp:coreProperties>
```

The core.xml can be accessed by renaming the *.xlam file to *.zip. This zip-archive contains several xml-files...